# GrayLog2 Email Alert Callback variables

Tags: graylog2

By default Graylog2 seems to use these variables in it's email alert callbacks:

```
Date: ${check_result.triggeredAt} 
Stream ID: ${stream.id} 
Stream title: ${stream.title} 
Stream URL: ${stream_url}
```

What are the others that are available?

Is {source} and {path} available? The documentation is non-existent regarding alert callbacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use

```
${foreach backlog message}${message.source}${end}
```

Comment: ${message.source} works. unfortunately ${message.path} doesn't

Answer (score 4):

Try to use

```
message.fields.yourfield (e.g. message.fields.path)
```

Source : http://docs.graylog.org/en/1.3/pages/streams.html

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to key off of any field that shows up in the default search.

So for standard syslog

```
message.timestamp
message.source
message.message
message.level
message.process_id
message.application_name
message.facility
```

The syntax used in the email template can be found here.
https://code.google.com/p/jmte/

Comment: tried message.level and my alerts failed with errors. _com.floreysoft.jmte.message.ParseException: Error while parsing 'message.level' at location (14:36): Property 'level' on object_